# How to extract a floating number from a string but excluding other number in the same string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

"You have selected: 7 Year Fixed Price 8.25¢/item"

How do I extract only "8.25" from this string in C#?

I have tried the following regex options:
`(\d+)(?:\.(\d{1,2}))?` and `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`  but both extract only "7", which is the first number it finds.

Comment: What is the rule? Try just `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\D*$)` to extract the number that has no digits after it.

Comment: Do you have more examples? Are they always formatted this exact way?
Can the “7” sometimes be a floating number also? For example 8.5 year” seems entirely plausible
Can you match on the “¢/item” or does that change?

Comment: Yes, more examples make it more robust.

Comment: Do you create the string yourself or are you getting it from an external source?

Comment: The text is coming from a Sharepoint list and the string content varies from list item to list item. I will update the question more with C# code example. I think coliveira's solution solved it, I'm testing it now. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\d` in C#... It catches non-classical Unicode digits, like the Devanagari ones (०१२...)... Use `[0-9]` and live happy(er). See for example https://dotnetfiddle.net/vjmOTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific example you can use a [named capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) and try something like this:

```
(?<float>\d+\.\d+)
```

Here is a quick demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dm78d7

Comment: Thank you coliveira

Answer (score 2):

Use

```cs
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\p{Sc}/item)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ePeKdX/1/).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{Sc}                 a currency sign
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /item                  '/item'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```